# Saving a scipy.sparse matrix directly as a regular txt file

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `scipy.sparse` matrix (`csr_matrix()`). But I need to save it to a file not in the `.npz` format but as a regular `.txt` or `.csv` file. My problem is that I don't have enough memory to convert the sparse matrix into a regular `np.array()` and then save it to a file. Is there a way to have the data as a sparse matrix in memory but save it directly as a regular matrix in the form:

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

to the disk? Or is there a way to "unzip" a `.npz` file without loading it into memory inside Python? (like for example gunzip or unzip in Bash).

Comment: You can write your matrix manually in to a csv file and not writing any npz files, does it handles your requirement?

Comment: Also, do you only need writing it into a file, or you need to read it later on ( with the memory issue ). And by saying `but save it directly as a regular matrix to the disk` you need your csv or txt files that contains all your zeros too?

Comment: csv format is 2d.   CSR format has 4 pieces of information, shape, data, indices, indptr. The `npz! saves those as 4 npy files. How do you propose addressing that difference?.

Comment: If you convert the CSR to COO, the info is in 3 1d arrays of the same size, data, row, col.  Stack those, and save them as a 3 column csv.  You could then load that and recreate the COO from them.  You may need to save the shape separately (if it can't be deduced from the max row/col values..

Comment: scipy.io.mmwrite can write a Matrix-Market file from a sparse COO array.  I haven't used it.

Comment: @meshkati that would be ideal, but do you know a command to do that? The problem is that I need to work on a sparse matrix and the just save it as a regular csv or txt file. (Not enough memory to allocate a non-sparse matrix). Regarding your 2nd comment. I will only need to read from it and I also need all the zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to new question:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse, io
A = sparse.eye(5, format='csr') * np.pi
np.set_printoptions(precision=16, linewidth=1000)
with open('matrix.txt', 'a') as f:
    for row in A:
        f.write(str(row.toarray()[0]))
        f.write('\n')

# [3.141592653589793 0.                0.                0.                0.               ]
# [0.                3.141592653589793 0.                0.                0.               ]
# [0.                0.                3.141592653589793 0.                0.               ]
# [0.                0.                0.                3.141592653589793 0.               ]
# [0.                0.                0.                0.                3.141592653589793]
```

And with begin/end brackets:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse, io
A = sparse.eye(5, format='csr') * np.pi
np.set_printoptions(precision=16, linewidth=1000)
with open('matrix.txt', 'a') as f:
    for i, row in enumerate(A):
        f.write('[' if (i == 0) else ' ')
        f.write(str(row.toarray()[0]))
        f.write(']' if (i == A.shape[0] - 1) else '\n')

# [[3.141592653589793 0.                0.                0.                0.               ]
#  [0.                3.141592653589793 0.                0.                0.               ]
#  [0.                0.                3.141592653589793 0.                0.               ]
#  [0.                0.                0.                3.141592653589793 0.               ]
#  [0.                0.                0.                0.                3.141592653589793]]
```

You may have to fiddle with `set_printoptions` depending on your data.

---

Answer to original question, which did not require that the matrix be written as dense.

[Harwell-Boeing format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html#harwell-boeing-files) is plain text:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse, io
A = sparse.eye(3, format='csr') * np.pi

# Default title                                                           0       
#              3             1             1             1
# RUA                        3             3             3             0
# (40I2)          (40I2)          (3E25.16)           
#  1 2 3 4
#  1 2 3
#   3.1415926535897931E+00  3.1415926535897931E+00  3.1415926535897931E+00

io.hb_write('matrix.txt', A)  # saves as matrix.txt
A2 = io.hb_read('matrix.txt')
assert not (A2 != A).nnz  # efficient check for equality
```

So is [Matrix Market](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html#matrix-market-files):

```py
io.mmwrite('matrix', A)  # saves as matrix.mtx

# %%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real symmetric
# %
# 3 3 3
# 1 1 3.141592653589793e+00
# 2 2 3.141592653589793e+00
# 3 3 3.141592653589793e+00

A2 = io.mmread('matrix')
assert not (A2 != A).nnz
```

---

If you want an even simpler *format*, although it involves more code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
A = sparse.eye(10, format='csr')*np.pi

np.savetxt('data.txt', A.data)
np.savetxt('indices.txt', A.indices, fmt='%i')
np.savetxt('indptr.txt', A.indptr, fmt='%i')
```

To load:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
indices = np.loadtxt('indices.txt', dtype=np.int32)
indptr = np.loadtxt('indptr.txt', dtype=np.int32)

A2 = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr))
assert not (A2 != A).nnz
```

But the important idea is that all you need to save are the `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` attributes of the `csr_matrix`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I might have not specified this enough in the question but I need to write the sparse matrix as a regular matrix to a file. So in the form: [ [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,1] ]. I have also edited the question, maybe now it is more clear.

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages those who post questions to mark accepted answers rather than thanking in the comments. (But good to hear.)